# How common is it for a science research paper to include direct quotes?

Tags: publications

Is there a consensus that direct quotes should never be used in such papers?

Comment: What sort of quotes? Quoting people or quoting other papers?

Comment: The latter. A professor told me today that scientific papers should never do this. Thoughts?

Comment: No.  There is not.

Comment: In the field of Human-Computer Interaction, direct quotes seem to be the norm based on the papers I've read.

Comment: For example, "Do Artifacts Have Politics" has approximately 70 quotations in it: cc.gatech.edu/~beki/cs4001/Winner.pdf

Comment: Perhaps the answer varies depending on the branch of science.  The OP did not reveal the branch involved where his professor rejected direct quotes.

Comment: "never" is too strong a word, but it's been a long time since I've seen a direct quote in a paper. But this is probably very different in humanities, politics, law, ...

Comment: Thanks for these thoughts. To answer @GEdgar, the field is biology.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I disagree, but you have to think about what you are doing. Anytime you use another's words directly you should quote them and indicate explicitly that it is a quote. This can be done with "quote" marks or otherwise, such as indentation. You also need to provide a reference to the source, say, in a footnote.

However, perhaps your professor is saying that, rather than quoting people's words directly, you *paraphrase* their arguments, etc. instead. Then you don't quote them. You still need the  reference, of course and need to be sure that your paraphrase is accurate. Your formatting, etc. needs to make it clear that the words are yours, not theirs.

But I would suggest you explore it further with your professor. Perhaps he or she has another idea in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. She is clear that she thinks that in the sciences one should always paraphrase (citing as you say) and never quote directly.

Comment: I wouldn't make it a _rule_ but it is probably a wise choice. When you quote it is hard to quote just a small part and still be true to the sense of the paper's arguments. Overquoting is a bad idea and giving the wrong impression from a small quote is also  a bad idea.  However, there are times when no words but the original words will suffice.

Comment: There are times quoting is the best choice. For example, quoting a senior leader's succinct comments which directly motivate your work. I agree with @Buffy in that direct quotes should be used sparingly and with purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Buffy, I also think your professor wants you not to quote exactly "the Quote", but consider paraphrasing them.

You see Plagiarism software are not intelligent enough to understand what is in your mind. Software like Turnitin will take your "copied quote" as a plagiarised text, which might hamper the quality of your paper.

Comment: I’ve never used the software in question, but I’m skeptical. Software for detecting plagiarism that gives false positives on quotations is practically useless in many cases, if not most.